# Spring session and security context integration

Tags: spring-security, spring-session

How to integrate Spring Session with Spring Security?

The problem is Spring Session does not set session attribute "SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT" to current SecurityContext. And I have error:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

This filter fix it:

```
public static class SessionSecurityContextIntegarionFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = servletRequest.getSession(false);
        if (null != session && session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT") != null) {
            SecurityContextHolder.setContext((SecurityContext) session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT"));
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

How to integrate Spring Session with Spring Security?